# DCM4CHE retrieve value based on tag in a sequence

Tags: java, xml, dcm4che

Using DCM4CHE to retrieve values based on the tag name in plain xml is pretty straightforward.

For example if I want to retrieve the value of the attribute AccessionNumber:

```
String accessiongNumber = attribute.getString(Tag.AccessionNumber);
```

But what is the best approach when dealing with Sequence?  I want to retrieve a value using its Tag name, but the value is 5 layers deep inside a Sequence.

In this case, I can get to the Sequence I want with:

```
Sequence recordSequence = attribute.getSequence(Tag.RecordSequence);
```

Is there a way to retrieve a value by its tag directly once I have the sequence that the value is embedded in?

Comment: recordSequence.get(#).getString(Tag.Something)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Attributes.getNestedDataset methods. These will get you the attributes in the sequence. Something like:

```
Attributes refStudy = attribute.getNestedDataset(Tag.ReferencedStudySeequence, 0);
String refSopiuid = refStudy.getString(Tag.ReferencedSOPInstanceUID);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  But in my case, after the first getNestedDataset, there are additional nested datasets within it. I am looking for a value with the Tag "NumericValue", but multiple instances exist. The only way to tell which "NumericValue" is the right one is by looking at the value of the node above it with the Tag "CodeMeaning". Is there a way to add a if statement to your answer that checks the node above "NumericValue" has the tag "CodeMeaning" and contains a specific value I designate?

Comment: Certainly you can code whatever is necessary. The getNestedDataset( sequence, i) gets the i'th item in the sequence; you can get any of the items (or iterate over them). Similarly, the 'items' themselves are Attributes that may contain further sequences, or more than just a single tag.

Comment: So going further, if I want to find a specific node, do I need to iterate through the entire nested dataset in a depth first search?  My data has many layers, is there a way that can get all instances of a keyword no matter which layer the instance resides?  Thanks.

Comment: If you just want to search the whole of the Attributes, you should use a visitor pattern and implement the Attributes.Visitor interface. Implement the visit method to perform what task you need. The Attributes.accept(Visitor, true) method will then 'visit' each attribute in the tree. I'll note this is probably less efficient than getting the sequence and items directly, but if you are just looking for an attribute 'wherever it may be' then certainly use the visitor.

Comment: That make sense.  Guess the visitor pattern is the way to go.  Thanks.